# How to checkout git repo with an specific revision in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, aws-code-deploy

I am running Jenkins with git, s3 and aws-codedeploy. for deploy build application over s3 and it trigger aws codedeploy for post deployment process.
The above setup is running perfectly.

I am getting issue whenever I run jenkins job, my job all time clone git repo then upload a zip of build/contents to s3 then aws-codedeploy deploy full zip on my servers.

But I want when I run jenkin job it is take specific git revision clone only not for full contents and build deployment with that only.

Please help me out on the above issue. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8):

As git treats any branch as a pointer to commit, you can specify the commit in branch specifier.

**EDIT (reply to comment):**
What you call a branch, is in fact just a pointer to a particular commit. Git has no such branches as svn; thus if you want to deploy a specific commit, you just supply it.

I understand you don't want to change to job every time you need to build it. You can make the build [parametrized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nosP.png) and then [use the parameter as branch specifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk6y8.png).

Comment: thanks for your ans, but I want to build particular commit from  branch, like in "Branch Specifier" I given */master but I want deploy with specific commit/revision id.

Comment: Can you do this on a pipeline?  I've tried providing the full sha and keep on getting no revisions found.  I think the GitScm plugin just pulls refs for tag/branches and doesn't support all commit ids even though its javadoc says it can do this

Comment: I didn't try actually but it should be possible. Do you have any code snippet you tried?

Comment: @PeterKahn You need to specify a valid refspec, otherwise Jenkins will try use the parameter string without expanding it and it will fail. Specify something valid like ` +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` for the refspec (under Advanced) and then add "Advanced clone behaviors" under "Additional Behaviours" and check the "Honor refspec on initial clone" option. Then Jenkins will do a git fetch with the valid refspec, and then a checkout with the expanded parameter value.

Comment: for me specific-commit-id-case works if I set set `refspec` to the commit id and let `branches` be `["FETCH_HEAD"]` - this way the commit get's fetched and checked out. `checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "FETCH_HEAD"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'my.repo', refspec="<commit-id>"]]])`

Answer (score 1):

In `Pre Steps` add this script under the `Execute shell`:

```
# update the local git repository
git fetch 

# pull the desired branch
git pull origin <branch>

# checkout the specific commit you want.
git checkout <commit version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Jenkins Pipeline**.

I can deploy old commit (any old commit), just run checkout in **gitlab** docker image, before deploy:

```
node {
stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm
}

docker.image('docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-ce').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {
    stage('git checkout') {
        sh 'git checkout ${REV_VER}'
        }
}
```

After this, i use any other docker image for build, and deploy.

Example:

```
docker.image('openjdk:8').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {
        stage('build') {
            build process*
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            deploy process*
        }
}
```

REV_VER, this is string parametr in Jenkins config.

Default variable - REV_VER (in Jenkins config) - *Develop* (my work branch).

But if you need deploy any old commit, just change variable on short ID commit (like "5221e28") in string REV_VER, when you run "Build with Parametrs"

p.s. OMG, i hope, you understand what i wrote, because my English is very bad =)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of [git](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#git-git) plugin:

> NOTE: The checkout step is the preferred SCM checkout method. It provides significantly more functionality than the git step.

Following above I made the version using [checkout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-check-out-from-version-control) with credentials:

```
def branchDeployName = 'd5e043c80b51067c397ae12567005efde5b2517f' //commit ID
/*or simply*/
//def branchDeployName = '*/master' //branch name
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', 
  branches: [[name: branchDeployName]], 
  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
  extensions: [], 
  submoduleCfg: [], 
  userRemoteConfigs: [
    [credentialsId: 'ac3a0ae1-d3aa-1111-ac70-cba42f82e760', 
     url: 'https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git']
  ]
])
```